# Why does xctool crash at NSRegularExpression matching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, xctool

For some strange unknown reason this test fails when running it in xctool (0.1.16) but passes when I run it through XCode.

```
- (void)testGetAppleIdfa
{
    NSString *sample_uuid = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];

    // For regex pattern matching to verify if it's of UUID
    NSString *pattern = @"[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}";
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [sample_uuid length]);
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:sample_uuid options:0 range:searchRange];

    NSLog(@"UUID generated: %@", sample_uuid);

    XCTAssertEqual([matches count], 1, @"UUID generated doesn't match the UUID RFC");
}
```

The reason why it's odd is because I use the *exact* same code, but replace the `sample_uuid` with `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]`.

This is what xctool spits out in the console:

```
2014-06-19 05:50:25.677 xctest[11190:303] LaunchServices: failed to get advertiserID
Unknown File:0: *** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00b331e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x007a68e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00b32fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x00079086 -[NSRegularExpression(NSMatching) enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:] + 215
    4   Foundation                          0x00042735 -[NSRegularExpression(NSMatching) matchesInString:options:range:] + 143
    5   SnowplowTests                       0x02f09462 -[TestUtils testGetAppleIdfa] + 338
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00b2791d __invoking___ + 29
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00b2782a -[NSInvocation invoke] + 362
    8   XCTest                              0x20103c6c -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 221
    9   XCTest                              0x20103d7b -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 111
    10  otest-shim-ios.dylib                0x00008cc7 XCPerformTestWithSuppressedExpectedAssertionFailures + 172
    11  otest-shim-ios.dylib                0x00008c15 XCTestCase_performTest + 31
    12  XCTest                              0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
    13  XCTest                              0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    14  XCTest                              0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
    15  XCTest                              0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    16  XCTest                              0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
    17  XCTest                              0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    18  XCTest                              0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
    19  XCTest                              0x201066ba +[XCTestProbe runTests:] + 183
    20  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x007b8743 +[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    21  xctest                              0x0000233e xctest + 4926
    22  xctest                              0x00002590 xctest + 5520
    23  xctest                              0x00002671 xctest + 5745
    24  xctest                              0x00002007 xctest + 4103
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x01687701 start + 1
```

):

From I figured out through trial-and-error that the test crashes at `NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:sample_uuid options:0 range:searchRange];` when it calls `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:`. Again, it passes with a different UUID generator that gives the exact same format.

Side notes: This isn't supposed to match type 4 UUIDs that's why the regular expression is as is.

EDIT: When I run xctools from a terminal using `xctool -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 build test` I get the above error. However, when I run the test through XCode I get my UUID in NSLog and it passes.

Comment: failed to get advertiserID <--- I'd look into this if I were you.  It is likely you are getting an empty string because of it.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but the stacktrace is a bit more odd. Also, I do get an advertiserID since it runs in the unit test environment within XCode. Isn't that just xctool with some fancy integration?

Comment: Also this question is similar and the person that answers it shows that the advertiserID is obtained in their tests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022360/what-is-this-vendorid-error-message-associated-with-cannot-connect-to-itunes-f

Comment: Log your UUID string and see what you are getting back for each.

Comment: I do with `NSLog(@"UUID generated: %@", sample_uuid);` but when I run xctools straight from the console it crashes as shown above, but runs fine (and shows my UUID) in the console.

I'll update my question to include this.

Comment: I mean put the log *before* it crashes obviously :p it even says that you are getting a nil argument.

Comment: Well call me stupid... I'm getting `(null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ExtremeMan on Github:

> I was able to reproduce the issue you mentioned. The problem is that
>   Xcode now run all tests as application tests and xctool still
>   distinguishes between logic and application tests.
>
> I was able to make your test passing when test bundle has associated
>   application and so it was considered as application test.
>
> More details you can find here:
>   [What is this vendorID error message associated with "Cannot Connect to iTunes" for in-app purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022360/what-is-this-vendorid-error-message-associated-with-cannot-connect-to-itunes-f).

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that `xctool` is launching the same simulator as `Xcode`.

Note that you are not specifying any simulator in your command

```
xctool -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 build test
```

because the `-sdk` command is used only when building but ignored when starting the simulator.

You should add something like

```
-destination 'name=iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit),OS=7.1'
```

Comment: I tried adding the destination to no avail. How would I know the exact configuration XCode is using in order to verify this?

Comment: @jonalmeida You always know what simulator you are launching from Xcode, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I do. I meant, how would verify if there are any other flags added to what XCode executes from what I'm executing via the console (besides the destination option).